# masking input for each neuron, is it possible?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

let's say I have an input dataframe, rows are number of data, columns are 5 features: ft1, ft2,.....,ft5.

Then I have a simple binary classification neural network which the hidden layer has 2 neurons. something like this:
[image: simple representation]

Can I control the input that being fed into each neuron? like only ft1, 3, 5 to neuron 1 and only ft2, 4 to neuron 2?

The first thing I can think of is masking, but it seems not work like that, maybe I can tweak the weight? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I control the input that being fed into each neuron?

Yes.

You are describing the architecture of a neural net,
how it is wired up.

Rather than a "fully connected" layer,
you want neuron1 to be only connected to odd input features,
and neuron2 to be only connected to even ones.
You build the NN, so yes, of course you can construct it in that way.

Equivalently, you might choose to use a fully connected layer
which forces Weights to be `0` for even inputs to neuron1,
and similarly for odd inputs to neuron2.

Since the two neurons do not share weights,
this would be different from a Siamese architecture.

Comment: thanks, can you give some hint/link on how to do this? Thank you very much